# Adding a counter to a DataTemplate

Tags: xaml, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate for an ItemsControl that outputs a Grid with some binded controls, and this works as expected.

However, I want the first column of the Grid to output a counter of each Grid made.

For example...

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="X" /> <!-- I want a counter to go here -->
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want that first TextBlock to display 1, 2, 3, 4, etc... as the DataTemplate outputs new Grids.

Any ideas on the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `AlternationCount` and `AlternationIndex` of `ItemsControl`. Like,

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AlternationCount="{Binding Items.Count}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This will give you `0` based index; you can use `IValueConverter` if any changes needed.